# Delete all dataset without deleting one by one in AWS Cognito

Tags: java, android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito.

And my Identity ID is having 20 datasets. I want to perform delete for all of my datasets inside the  Identity ID.

What i did is, I will get the ID of all datasets one by one and deleting it locally and syncing the deleted one.

```
  Dataset dataset = getDataSet(“datasetid”); // getDataset() will return the dataset of particular detest ID
  dataset.delete(); // delete will happen locally
  sync(true); // and sync will happen for each local delete
```

Delete and sync will happen for all datasets, So totally 20 sync call will be made.

I feel its taking to much time? To many sync calls.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way for now. [Cognito API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) only has method to delete a [single record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDataset.html). And thus this (bulk deletion) is not present in the [java library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java).